# Python string formatting: For loops?

Tags: python, string, jinja2

I really enjoy the Django/Jinja style of formatting. I understand wanting to keep logic and presentation separate, but the if statements and for loops are ideal when reporting a changing amount of data.

I am creating a "Report" class that returns some information about the inputs and outputs of a function in a more verbose way, and what I would like is to have a string like:

```
template="""
INPUTS:
{{% for key,value in inputsdict.items() %}}
  {{key}}: {{value}}
{{% endfor #}}

OUTPUTS:
{{% for key,value in outputsdict.items() %}}
  {{key}}: {{value}}
{{% endfor #}}
"""
```

and then I could just call a classic `template.format(**kwargs)`

I am wondering if Jinja is my best bet to do this, or whether python has a native, lightweight string loop formatting functionality of some kind that I should be looking at.

Edit: Additionally, if Jinja is my best bet, I would really appreciate an example of how to use it outside of a web-oriented environment. The docs are kind of hard to navigate.

Comment: You can't expect a templating engine (in effect a macro-language) to be subbed just via a single replace. You can use `jinja2` or others outside of a web environment (in fact it's perfectly useable outside that context), just give it a suitable environmental and context to work and get a your new string back...

Comment: the thing is that jinja packs in way more than I need, and doesn't necessarily adhere to the { | <20 } style formatting of regular python. However, I got something going.

Answer (score 3):

Generate your data from your for loops and then put them in the results.

There's no need to over-use the format template system. Just use it for the pieces where it's needed.

```
inputs  = ['%s: %s' % (k, v) for k, v in input_dict.items()]
outputs = ['%s: %s' % (k, v) for k, v in output_dict.items()]
print '\n'.join('INPUTS:',  '\n  '.join(inputs),
                '', 
                'OUTPUTS:', '\n  '.join(outputs))
```

You could make the `inputs`/`outputs` creation step a function, or use something from the [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library for pretty printing.